# How do I run html script in flask-admin panel columns?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have added a property to Quiz model that returns html code.

```
@property
def create_questions(self):
    if self.no_of_questions_created == self.quiz_capacity:
        return '<a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit Questions</button></a>'
    elif self.no_of_questions_created < self.quiz_capacity:
        return '<a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary">Add more Questions</button></a>'
    elif self.no_of_questions_created == None:
        return '<a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary">Add Questions</button></a>'
```

I expected a bootstrap button to be displayed in column section, but I got plain html text.
[table view link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzTk7.png)

How can I get the desired button here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself using Markup() solved the problem.

```
from flask import Markup

def create_questions(self):
    if self.no_of_questions_created == self.quiz_capacity:
        return Markup('<a href=""><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit Questions</button></a>')
```

[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqxDN.png)